# How do i replicate these plots using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

[plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THxiG.png)

This is what I have tried so far.
The box plot is kind of close, but the other plot is way off.

```
ggplot(data_anova, aes(x = delay, y = soa, color = age)) +
  geom_jitter() +
  geom_line(position=position_jitter(w=0, h=0)) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
     panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.position = "none") + 
  labs(x = "SoA", 
       y = "delay") 

ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = soa, fill = age)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), legend.position = "none") + 
   labs(x = "age", 
        y = "pse")
```

data

```
structure(list(age = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), sex = c("f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "f", "m", "m", "m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m", "m", "f", "f", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f"), soa = c(0.1, 0.01, 0.8, 0.41, 0.86, 0.58, 0.43, 0.73, 0.23, 0.88, 0.73, 0.15, 0.66, 0.53, 0.64, 0.28, 0.47, 0.84, 0.93, 0.41, 0.23, 0.59, 0.64, 0.36), delay = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 300L, 300L, 300L, 400L, 400L, 400L, 500L, 500L, 500L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 700L, 700L, 700L, 800L, 800L, 800L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()`? Without data we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you mean like this?

Answer (score 0):

For a start, something for your panel A:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = delay, y = soa, color = sex)) +
  geom_point(pch=21, size = 2.5) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", se = F) + 
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 1, 0.1), limits = c(0,1))+
  theme_minimal() + 
  labs(x = "Delay time [ms]", 
       y = "'Yes' response [ratio]", 
       color = "") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("Children", "Young Adults"), values = c("blue", "red")) + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        legend.position = c(.19,.15), 
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=2))
```